# SQL: use CASE with AS

Tags: sql, case

I'm working on a long SQL request and I want to use CASE inside but I don't know how to write it.
My request looks like :

```
SELECT (
    SELECT id FROM first_table ft 
    INNER JOIN second_table st ON st.id = ft.id
    INNER JOIN third_table tt ON tt.id = ft.id WHERE tt.second = 0 LIMIT 1
) as key
```

I want to add something like :

```
CASE key WHEN 'One' THEN 'Two' END
```

I tried to add this at the end but it didn't work :

```
SELECT (
    SELECT id FROM first_table ft
    INNER JOIN second_table st
        ON st.id = ft.id
    INNER JOIN third_table tt
        ON tt.id = ft.id WHERE tt.second = 0 LIMIT 1
) as key CASE WHEN key = 'One' THEN 'Two' END
```

My goal is to edit key along its value

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: your question is not so clare. Post some code for help other to help you(also the one that doesn't work)

Comment: Tag your question with your RDBMS. Providing sample input and output would also help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a subquery:

```
SELECT
   key,
   CASE WHEN key = 'One' THEN 'Two' END test_column
FROM
   (
      SELECT 
         id key
      FROM
         first_table ft
         INNER JOIN second_table st ON st.id = ft.id
         INNER JOIN third_table tt ON tt.id = ft.id
      WHERE 
         tt.second = 0
      LIMIT 1
   ) data
```